# iPhone Store Kit returning invalid product ID errors

Tags: iphone, in-app-purchase, storekit

I am trying to test In App Purchases on my iPhone and running into a problem where the product IDs I request information for end up being returned to me as invalid product IDs in the "didRecieveResponse" method.

I have:

- Created an in store product associated with this app.  It's bundle ID matches everything else.  It has been cleared for sale and approved by the developer.
- Made sure my new provisioning profile has in store app purchases enabled and it has the full app name: "com.domain.appname"
- Made sure this is the provisioning profile being used to sign the app to my iPhone.
- Made sure that "com.domain.appname" is the app ID used to build the provisioning profile.
- Made sure that "com.domain.appname" is used in my plist file as the bundle identifier.

Everything seems to be in place, however I still get my products returned to me as invalid IDs.

This is the code I am using:

```
- (void)requestProductData {
   SKProductRequest *request = [[SKProductsRequest alloc] initWithProductIdentifiers: [NSSet setWithObject: @"com.domain.appname.productid"]];
   request.delegate = self;
   [request start];
}

- (void)productsRequest:(SKProductsRequest *)request didReceiveResponse:(SKProductsResponse *)response
{
   NSArray *myProducts = response.products;
   NSArray *myInvalidProducts = response.invalidProductIdentifiers;

   for(int i = 1; i < myInvalidProducts.count; ++i)
   {
      std::cout <<"invalid product id = " << [[myInvalidProducts objectAtIndex:i] UTF8String] << std::endl;
   }

   for(int i = 0; i  < myProducts.count; ++i)
   {
      SKProduct * myProduct = [myProducts objectAtIndex:i];
      std::cout << "Product Info:"  << std::endl;
      std::cout << "\tlocalizedTitle         = "  << [[myProduct localizedTitle] UTF8String]  << std::endl;
      std::cout << "\tlocalizedDescription   = "  << [[myProduct localizedDescription] UTF8String]  << std::endl;
      std::cout << "\tproductIdentifier      = "  << [[myProduct productIdentifier] UTF8String]  << std::endl;
      std::cout << "\tprice                  = "  << [[myProduct price] doubleValue]  << std::endl;
      std::cout << "\tpriceLocale            = "  << [myProduct priceLocale]  << std::endl;
   }

   [request autorelease];
}
```

All my product IDs show up in the invalid printouts and none of them show up in the "Product Info:" printouts.

Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated...

P.S.  Yes, this is built as Objective-c/c++.

Comment: perhaps a dumb question, but did you actually go to iTunes Connect and add the in-app-purchase product that you're querying?

Comment: Not a dumb question at all.  I did add the in-app-purchase.  I checked its ID, and it all matches up.  It has been cleared for sale and validated by the developer.

Comment: this probably isn't it either, but I noticed in your sample code you're calling "initWithProductIndentifiers" instead of "initWithProductIdentifiers"....

Comment: @EToreo-Hi.i'm trying InAppPurchase in Cocos2d-x.waiting somebody to guide me.can you able to guide me for this IAP.i'm new for this.Thanks in Advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK, so after doing everything I could possibly think of and reading every forum out there, here is what worked:

Redo EVERYHING.

1. Remove ALL your provisioning profiles from the Xcode Organizer.
2. Close Xcode.
3. Create a New App ID.
4. Create a new Provisioning profile with the new App ID.
5. Create a new Distribution Provisioning profile with the new App ID.
6. Create a new App in iTunes Connect
7. Start Xcode, install your two new provisioning profiles.  Update yoru bundle ID to match.  Also make sure your id strings that the app requests are updated to reflect your bundle id.
8. Build your project in Distribution mode with the new Distribution Provisioning profile.
9. Upload your new binary.  (Leave it un-rejected)
10. Set up your test in-app purchase.
11. Build your project in Debug mode with the new Provisioning profile.
12. Test request.

This is what it took to get my store working.  My best guess is that the Apple back end servers get screwed up sometimes and you just need to start from scratch.

Hope this helps everyone!

Comment: were you able to create a new app with the same name as before?

Answer (score 6):

I tried everything suggested in the Apple forums and here, and still couldn't get it to work. Found the solution - your app needs to be transferred by Xcode for the sandbox to be enabled.

Obvious, right? Well, if you are working with an update to an existing account, the device will still treat it as an App Store-installed app.

Delete it, then transfer it again. It should work now :)

Comment: I am also getting invalid product identifier, may I ask what you mean by transferring the app by Xcode? How do I actually do this? Thanks in advance.

Comment: @bobo He means running the app on your device from within Xcode, rather than on the simulator. @Hector - thanks, you saved me all kinds of frustration!

Comment: You should delete the app from your device, then Build and Run on Device again. My problem arised from doing a Build and Run against an iTunes (Production) version of the app, which meant that my new version was still pointing to Apple's production iTunes servers, instead of a sandbox.

Answer (score 4):

Deleting the app on the testing iPhone and reinstalling it worked. Also I had also waited 8 hours since submitting the in-app purchase item.

Comment: Worked for me as well when the issue happenend.

Comment: Got this problem, again - seems like it turns up almost everytime I implement IAP into yet another app. Deleting the app, doing a clean + reinstall from XCode fixed it. I believe this fixed it previous times too.

Answer (score 3):

Please Go through the steps below:

1. Log in to iTunes connect using your developer account (https://itunesconnect.apple.com/WebObjects/iTunesConnect.woa/wo/).
2. Go to the Tab - **"Contracts, Tax, and Banking"**
3. Check the Request Contracts and Contracts in Process sections.
4. Check out the **"iOS Paid Applications"** and there Contact Info , Bank Info and Tax Info are need to Set up.
5. When "iOS Paid Applications" cell will move to Contracts in Effect section, I will be able to use Products for in App Purchase.

Please go through the link below for more information:
http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#technotes/tn2259/_index.html

Answer (score 2):

Please note that when iPhone is jailbroken the **AppSync** packet breaks **in-app-purchasing testing completely.**
AppSync is installed with Install0us as a dependency.

You don't have to restore iOS completely, **just uninstall AppSync in Cydia to test in-app-purchases with success**.

All tips from all forums, tutorials and comments about fixind 'invalid product' did not work for me until I removed AppSync.

Answer (score 1):

I've been having a similar problem with a new app (v1.0 not yet released in store) that I was trying to add in app purchases too. I set everything up, added products, etc. and my products ALWAYS came back as invalid when I did an SKProductsRequest.

I was about to give up on the entire process, when I saw a tangentially-related post on the Apple developer forums. It suggested deleting the app from the test device and and doing a fresh build+install. That did the trick.

Just to be sure, I tried it on another device that was giving me the same trouble, and it fixed it there too.

It's just a guess, but I think that if the device has a build on it that was made with a provisioning profile that was created BEFORE you add IAP, you need to remove that build and put on a fresh one using the IAP profile. (That is, simply replacing the app in place won't do the trick.)

Answer (score 1):

if nothing wrong in your code,
sometime it has return invalid productId 
just because, you may need a time over 10 hour for your changing info. taking effect.
Or, the productId invalid because something wrong are remained on your device, so you can try once more with delete your app and build it again.
with my experience,
hope it will helps.

Answer (score 0):

iTunes Connect interface for IAP has recently been updated that can cause Invalid : < Product ID > error.

You can now add an IAP in iTunes connect without setting the price which is defaulted to USD 0 and it'll let you save that entry.

The old version of the UI would complain when you press save if you didn't edit the price field beforehand.

It is very easy to miss this field out completely and any attempt to get information using that Product ID via any iOS call would result in Invalid : < Product ID > rather than telling you it found < Product ID > priced at USD 0.