# Is copying an Xcode iOS project going to cause problems with in app purchases?

Tags: ios, xcode, in-app-purchase, storekit

I have an app that uses in app purchases, and they worked fine when i tested them.  That app is now in the app store.  So I wanted to make a similar app, so i duplicated the project folder (in finder), renamed it, renamed the project in Xcode, changed the Identifier/Bundle ID, made a new app ID for it, made a provisioning profile for it, set it up in itunes connect (pretty much everything I did for the original app), but when i make a product request the array comes back empty.  The app's status is "waiting for upload" and the IAP status is "waiting for review".  Is there something besides the IDs that I need to change, that's lingering over from the original app that could be messing it up?  I've gone thru walkthroughs and double checked everything, so not sure what else it could be.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It turned out I needed to request only the product name, not com.companyname.app.productname...unlike my other app, which DID use the bundle ID...silly apple.

Answer (score 3):

There may be something wrong with the store as of December 12, 2011.

My in app purchases have suddenly stopped working today. I haven't changed any code, and the identifiers being returned as "invalid" match what's registered in iTunes Connect. I'll post again if I find something out anything more.

Comment: explains mine too.  i had an app released that day...bad timing.  people weren't happy.

Comment: Looks like maybe the app store wasn't to blame in my case. After more investigation, I found this thread: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1633072/iphone-store-kit-returning-invalid-product-id-errors, in which someone suggested deleting the app from the test device, rebuilding, and re-transferring to the test device. That worked for me. In this case, I think I had switched provisioning profiles, and sometimes when you do that, it doesn't properly clean itself off of the test device. Go figure.

Answer (score 0):

The only thing that matters is the bundle identifier. Also make sure to clean all caches and to do a full rebuild, but I assume that you knew that already.

Of course, also ensure that your provisioning/distribution certificates are valid.

Comment: what do you mean by a "full rebuild"?  I cleaned it and removed it from the device.

Comment: In XCode, do a Clean and then Build again.

Answer (score 0):

Have you also added the in-app purchases to the new app under iTunes Connect?